# How do you make all updates install automatically?

Tags: updates, appcenter

Can someone please explain to me how I would enable all updates to install automatically? Is there an option in AppCenter to do this? If not, when is it coming? If it's not coming... how would one do this?

Comment: Sorry, no answer to your question but that's a feature I'd like too...
Having a half mb update since yesterday that I installed 4 times, still pops up as uninstalled... Frustrating...

Comment: You'll get automatic upgrades if you install unattended-upgrades from commandline. Search and teach you how to install and configure appropiately to fix your needs Edit (03/20/20) :
Edit your question and copy-paste your /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades file.
I think you should fine tune this file.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades

Comment: @Paul that's exactly what i'm looking for. Thanks a lot

Comment: This works, but does not install OS or native elementary OS app updates out of the box. Does anyone know how to configure it to do so?

Answer (score 0):

well i think this gonna work, you can create a archive .sh with root permissions with this comand **sudo touch att_sis.sh**. run this command on the folder that you know. open with this command **sudo nano att_sis.sh**, this command will open the archive on terminal and type it this commands **sudo apt-get update && 
sudo apt-get upgrade -y && sudo apt autoremove -y** save and close the archive, after this in the same terminal run this command **sudo chmod +x att_sis.sh** after this go to config menu -> apps -> boot on the bottom will have a symbol to add program to your boot click there and select command line and type **cd /home/you_user/pathToTheArchive && ./att_sis.sh**. Doing this every boot of the system he will search for update, do the upgrade and remove unused packages